# Inverse function theorem clarification

Tags: real-analysis

The following confuses me:

In our script it says that the inverse function theorem furnishes(given the proper prerequisites) a bijective​ function from an open neighbourhood of $x_0$ to an open neighbourhood of $f(x_0)$, $x_0$ being the original point where the total derivative is invertible.

When reading the proof it seems to me that the domain of this function $f$ is merely an open set containing $x_0$, not actually a neighbourhood of $x_0$. Is this true?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: An open set containing $x_0$ is a neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Comment: Isn't for example (0,1) U (2,3) in R an open set containing 0.5 but not a neighbourhood of 0.5?

Comment: No. By definition, any open set containing $x$ is a(n open) neighborhood of $x$.

Comment: There might be different definitions in use, but the most standard one (I think) is that a neighbourhood of $x$ is a set containing an open set containing $x$. So that example is indeed a neighbourhood of 0.5 (an open neighbourhood, even).

Comment: Ok, so I guess someone should delete this question.